# Zurb Foundation, horizontally centering a 10 column in the 12 column grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Foundation wizards,

Having a difficult time trying to center a 10-column element in the default 12 column grid.

EDIT: filled out the code a bit more

I tried putting 1 columns on either side to no avail:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="large-1 column"><p></div>

<div class="large-10 columns">
<div class="row>five large-2 columns in here</div>
<div class="row>five large-2 columns in here</div>
<div class="row>five large-2 columns in here</div>
</div>

<div class="large-1 column"><p></div>

</div>
```

My goal is to have that 3x5 grid in the exact center of the page.  The 1 columns are currently not padding the 10 column to the center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Center the div by including the `large-centered` class, or `small-centered` depending on your needs:

```
<div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
    five 2 columns in here
</div>
```

And if you want to center the content of the `large-10` div you can add the `text-center` class that is included in F4:

```
<div class="large-10 large-centered columns text-center">
    five 2 columns in here
</div>
```

Also, don't forget to wrap your `column divs` in a `row div` or else the `columns` classes will not work. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKe2k/1/) as an example.

Comment: the .large-centered should not need to be added to the css since it is inside of Foundation.css by default

Comment: @Dylan look closely at the class, it's not just the `large-centered`. It's another class. Actually I could have used the built-in `text-center` class instead. I think I'll add it. But thanks, for you've reminded me of it.

Comment: yes, it is technically `.columns.large-centered` however adding your original css editions would have been unnecessary since Travis' snippet already had columns declared before the center class. Wasn't calling you out, was just pointing out that it was an unnecessary addition @von-v

Comment: No worries @Dylan, I appreciate comments and even call out if I did something wrong. :)   "Travis' snippet already had columns declared before the center class" - I do not understand this though. There's nothing in there that indicates the text will be centered.

Comment: at no point in his question did he ever ask to have centered text, he just wants a 10 column container in the middle of his 12 column grid ;) @von-v

Comment: I think I was reading too many questions, the centered text thing got into the mix here :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the text in the column or center the div on the page (equal margins on either side)?

If you're just trying to center the div (and not its contents) this works:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns one"></div>
                <div class="columns ten">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="columns one"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  Am I missing something?  I clarified the HTML being used.

Comment: What are you trying to center, the column or the text in the column?  Or both?

Comment: Take a look at the source code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/designbymichael/2kfCq/  and try that out in your Foundation environment.  I threw the borders in there just to see the boundaries of the three columns and the center ten-column div element is centered in the row itself.

I tried your source code and it obviously didn't work — granted, I'm using Foundation 2.2, and the classes you used aren't even in that version.